# Is it possible to simulate keyboard/mouse event in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

Imagine that a NodeJS module, when invoked from console, outputs some introductory messages and then waits for user input (click enter or esc). This module already has and does everything we require, except that - wait-for-user-input prompt. So we wonder (I'm personally very new to NodeJS) if it is possible to execute console module programmatically and trigger an input event on it, so that it doesn't wait and proceed with the job right away?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use possibly use [RobotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs) for this.

Example code:

```js
var robot = require("robotjs");

// Type user's password or something. 
robot.typeString("abc123");
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I've just used it to simulate an enter key press successfully with `robot.keyTap('enter')`.

Comment: Thanks! It's super easy, and cross platform!

Comment: Sadly does not seem to be maintained at the moment...

Answer (score 17):

As Jason mentioned you could use [RobotJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs) for key simulation but there are couple of steps require to correctly build robotJS for **Windows** paltform:

1. You would need windows build tools so run `npm install --global windows-build-tools` (would take some time as it's around 120MB)
2. run `npm install robotjs --save-dev`
   You're done!.
   If this is for **electron** app then you would also require below 3rd step:
3. run `npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=1.7.9 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --abi=57`

   (1.7.9 is my `electron --version` and abi is for my corresponding `node --version` 8.7 installed, you can check abi version for node version [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) [look for NODE_MODULE_VERSION column])

Comment: Why `--save-dev` instead of `--save`?

Comment: @DLight That depends on the purpose of your package and the way this llibrary is used within it; if this package is a stand-alone application, then it doesn't matter. If this package is a library, then it should be in normal dependencies unless it is only used for development (since `devDependencies`) are not installed if the package was installed from NPM.

Answer (score 8):

node-key-sender library is an alternative to RobotJs if you just need to send keys to your operational system. It is cross platform and very small lib.

Install it with `npm install --save-dev node-key-sender`.

And send "enter" to the keyboard using:

```
var ks = require('node-key-sender');
ks.sendKey('enter');
```

Check out the documentation page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-key-sender.

Comment: Unfortunately it requires a full blown java environment to work (it's just a wrapper for a jar file)!

Comment: Why `--save-dev` instead of `--save`?

Comment: Because they saving it as developer depedency instead of saving it in to running packages

Answer (score 4):

Responding to @Venryx. They are right that robotjs is going to have a delay, especially if you have to load node first, however, if you already have node loaded, it may be worth trying out

```
robot.setKeyboardDelay(0)
```

The default setting for a delay is 10ms. This helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried `robotjs` and `node-key-sender`, but they cause a substantial amount of delay/stuttering per key-event. (especially noticeable when sending them frequently)

To resolve this, I found a way to use `node-ffi-napi` to call the Windows user32 `SendInput` function directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50412529/2441655

In my case at least, this achieved substantially better performance. (however, a drawback is that it only works on Windows, of course)