# node.js mouse press event in the shell

Tags: javascript, events, node.js, mouse

Is it possible to track mouse click on the shell in node.js.

Something link:

```
process.on('mousepress', function(data){

});
```

Comment: kinda related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178372/is-it-possible-to-simulate-keyboard-mouse-event-in-nodejs

Comment: @RobW with vi (or vim) you can use your mouse

Comment: @3on I don't want to simulate but to track it.

Comment: It depends of your terminal, for example Terminal.app what a shame does not supports it but most other does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help: https://github.com/mscdex/node-ncurses

Comment: nice but I just see keyboard event, not mouse.

Comment: Me neither there is a 'hasMouse' feature, maybe an complete bindings or just not documented. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/mouse.html could help.

Comment: I think it's the best way, as you said ncurses already has mouse support just the binding not. I will try to make the mouse support for the binding.

Answer (score 1):

The `keypress` package has this feature:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress#listening-for-mousepress-events