# using SendInput in Node-FFI

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, winapi, node-ffi

I wanted to use the SendInput function from the windows Api in nodejs, using the FFI package.

My knowledge of C is limited so I can't really figure out what problem I have,
I'm basically trying to Virtually press a key on the keyboard.

That's the code I have:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require ('ref');
var struct = require ('ref-struct');

var keyboardInput = struct({
    'type': 'int',
    'wVK': 'int',
    'wScan': 'int',
    'dwFlags': 'int',
    'time': 'int',
    'dwExtraInfo': 'int64'
});

var keyboardInputPtr = ref.refType(keyboardInput);
var keyboard = new keyboardInput();
keyboard.type = 1;
keyboard.wVK = 0x41;
keyboard.wScan = 0;
keyboard.dwFlags = 2;
keyboard.time = 0;
keyboard.dwExtraInfo = 0;

var user32 = ffi.Library('user32', {
    'SendInput': [ 'int', [ 'uint', keyboardInputPtr, 'int' ] ]
});

setInterval(function(){
    var r = user32.SendInput(1, keyboard.ref(), 40);
    console.log(r);
}, 500);
```

It logs me a "1" in the console, shouldn't that mean it works? Because I don't get a key pressed when I open notepad.

Comment: `SendInput` places input in the hardware input queue. Whichever window (or thread, really) is in the foreground at the time this input event is picked up receives the input. So when you launch your application, naturally Notepad isn't the foreground window. At any rate, what you have described is your proposed solution. Now what **problem** are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Nobody ever has faking input to notepad as the final goal. What are you really trying to do. Quite possibly, even if you can fake it I to notepad your true goal won't be solved the same way.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to write a program that clicks a button (on the keyboard) into the current active window. With the interval it's basically like an auto clicker.

Comment: *"clicks a button (on the keyboard)"* - That doesn't make sense. Do you want to click a button, or do you want to generate keyboard input.

Comment: @IInspectable i'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but I want to generate a keyboard input, just like pressing the button "A" on the keyboard.

Comment: If you truly want to generate keyboard input (like an on-screen keyboard), `SendInput` is the right tool. You still have to make sure, that the right control is in the foreground, when you generated input.

Answer (score 7):

I finally found a way to use `node-ffi`/`node-ffi-napi` to input key-presses using the `SendInput` function! (current code below uses `node-ffi-napi`, since `node-ffi` has been unmaintained/broken; see edit history for `node-ffi` version, the api is almost exactly the same)

However, note that there are two ways you can call the SendInput function, as seen here: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=213617#p213617

In my case, I had to use the second (scan code) approach, because the first (virtual key) approach didn't work in the programs I needed the key simulation for.

Without further ado, here is the complete solution:

```
import keycode from "keycode";
import ffi from "ffi-napi";
import ref from "ref-napi";
import os from "os";
import import_Struct from "ref-struct-di";

var arch = os.arch();
const Struct = import_Struct(ref);

var Input = Struct({
    "type": "int",

    // For some reason, the wScan value is only recognized as the wScan value when we add this filler slot.
    // It might be because it's expecting the values after this to be inside a "wrapper" substructure, as seen here:
    //     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx
    "???": "int",
     
    "wVK": "short",
    "wScan": "short",
    "dwFlags": "int",
    "time": "int",
    "dwExtraInfo": "int64"
});

var user32 = ffi.Library("user32", {
    SendInput: ["int", ["int", Input, "int"]],
    MapVirtualKeyExA: ["uint", ["uint", "uint", "int"]],
});

const extendedKeyPrefix = 0xe000;
const INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1;
const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP       = 0x0002;
const KEYEVENTF_UNICODE     = 0x0004;
const KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE    = 0x0008;
//const MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0;

export class KeyToggle_Options {
    asScanCode = true;
    keyCodeIsScanCode = false;
    flags?: number;
    async = false; // async can reduce stutter in your app, if frequently sending key-events
}

let entry = new Input(); // having one persistent native object, and just changing its fields, is apparently faster (from testing)
entry.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
entry.time = 0;
entry.dwExtraInfo = 0;
export function KeyToggle(keyCode: number, type = "down" as "down" | "up", options?: Partial<KeyToggle_Options>) {
    const opt = Object.assign({}, new KeyToggle_Options(), options);
    
    // scan-code approach (default)
    if (opt.asScanCode) {
        let scanCode = opt.keyCodeIsScanCode ? keyCode : ConvertKeyCodeToScanCode(keyCode);
        let isExtendedKey = (scanCode & extendedKeyPrefix) == extendedKeyPrefix;

        entry.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        if (isExtendedKey) {
            entry.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
        }

        entry.wVK = 0;
        entry.wScan = isExtendedKey ? scanCode - extendedKeyPrefix : scanCode;
    }
    // (virtual) key-code approach
    else {
        entry.dwFlags = 0;
        entry.wVK = keyCode;
        //info.wScan = 0x0200;
        entry.wScan = 0;
    }

    if (opt.flags != null) {
        entry.dwFlags = opt.flags;
    }
    if (type == "up") {
        entry.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    }

    if (opt.async) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            user32.SendInput.async(1, entry, arch === "x64" ? 40 : 28, (error, result)=> {
                if (error) reject(error);
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    }
    return user32.SendInput(1, entry, arch === "x64" ? 40 : 28);
}

export function KeyTap(keyCode: number, opt?: Partial<KeyToggle_Options>) {
    KeyToggle(keyCode, "down", opt);
    KeyToggle(keyCode, "up", opt);
}

export function ConvertKeyCodeToScanCode(keyCode: number) {
    //return user32.MapVirtualKeyExA(keyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, 0);
    return user32.MapVirtualKeyExA(keyCode, 0, 0);
}
```

To use it, call:

```
KeyTap(65); // press the A key
```

Or, if you're using the [keycode npm package](https://github.com/timoxley/keycode):

```
import keycode from "keycode";
KeyTap(keycode.codes.a);
```

Comment: @truefusion It looks like you're right, though I can't seem to find proper documentation for the field. The page I linked in the code comment mentions the field but doesn't describe it at all or provide the possible values. (it just gives the plain-text reference "DUMMYUNIONNAME.mi")

Comment: to fixed the `MapVirtualKeyEx` issue, i used `MapVirtualKeyExA` instead and it worked : `user32.MapVirtualKeyExA(keyCode, 0, 0);` and `MapVirtualKeyExA: ["uint", ["uint", "uint", "int"]],`

Comment: @yaya Awesome! Thanks for the info. (I will update my answer once I've confirmed it on my computer.)

Comment: Sure. Here is my full code, so if you face any error you can check it also : https://pastebin.pl/view/f527be0e

Comment: @Venryx I too ran into the need for the `"???": "int"` "padding" member while running in the`x64` architecture. I believe that this is due to pointers within structs needing to be aligned to the size of pointers (8 bytes in the `x64` architecture). By adding that 4-byte spacing, you effectively aligned the pointer (`ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo`). I found another way to fix that: mark that field with type `pointer`, and `ref-struct-napi` will take care of the alignment for you. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Isn't the padding needed because the actual Win32 INPUT struct is a union of 3 different where the biggest is the mouse one? (it is 4 bytes longer) than the keyboard one.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a working example that presses the `a` key. It employs `ref-struct-napi` and `ref-union-napi` to accurately represent the `INPUT` structure.

```
const FFI = require('ffi-napi')
const StructType = require('ref-struct-napi')
const UnionType = require('ref-union-napi')
const ref = require('ref-napi')


const user32 = new FFI.Library('user32.dll', {
  // UINT SendInput(
  //   _In_ UINT cInputs,                     // number of input in the array
  //   _In_reads_(cInputs) LPINPUT pInputs,  // array of inputs
  //   _In_ int cbSize);                      // sizeof(INPUT)
  'SendInput': ['uint32', ['int32', 'pointer', 'int32']],
})

// typedef struct tagMOUSEINPUT {
//   LONG    dx;
//   LONG    dy;
//   DWORD   mouseData;
//   DWORD   dwFlags;
//   DWORD   time;
//   ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
// } MOUSEINPUT;
const MOUSEINPUT = StructType({
  dx: 'int32',
  dy: 'int32',
  mouseData: 'uint32',
  flags: 'uint32',
  time: 'uint32',
  extraInfo: 'pointer',
})

// typedef struct tagKEYBDINPUT {
//   WORD    wVk;
//   WORD    wScan;
//   DWORD   dwFlags;
//   DWORD   time;
//   ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
// } KEYBDINPUT;
const KEYBDINPUT = StructType({
  vk: 'uint16',
  scan: 'uint16',
  flags: 'uint32',
  time: 'uint32',
  extraInfo: 'pointer',
})

// typedef struct tagHARDWAREINPUT {
//   DWORD   uMsg;
//   WORD    wParamL;
//   WORD    wParamH;
// } HARDWAREINPUT;
const HARDWAREINPUT = StructType({
  msg: 'uint32',
  paramL: 'uint16',
  paramH: 'uint16',
})

// typedef struct tagINPUT {
//   DWORD   type;
//   union
//   {
//     MOUSEINPUT      mi;
//     KEYBDINPUT      ki;
//     HARDWAREINPUT   hi;
//   } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
// } INPUT;
const INPUT_UNION = UnionType({
  mi: MOUSEINPUT,
  ki: KEYBDINPUT,
  hi: HARDWAREINPUT,
})
const INPUT = StructType({
  type: 'uint32',
  union: INPUT_UNION,
})

const pressKey = (scanCode) => {
  const keyDownKeyboardInput = KEYBDINPUT({vk: 0, extraInfo: ref.NULL_POINTER, time: 0, scan: scanCode, flags: 0x0008})
  const keyDownInput = INPUT({type: 1, union: INPUT_UNION({ki: keyDownKeyboardInput})})
  user32.SendInput(1, keyDownInput.ref(), INPUT.size)

  const keyUpKeyboardInput = KEYBDINPUT({vk: 0, extraInfo: ref.NULL_POINTER, time: 0, scan: scanCode, flags: 0x0008 | 0x0002})
  const keyUpInput = INPUT({type: 1, union: INPUT_UNION({ki: keyUpKeyboardInput})})
  user32.SendInput(1, keyUpInput.ref(), INPUT.size)
}

pressKey(0x1E)
```

If you want to perform a single call to `SendInput` that includes multiple key presses, construct an array of `INPUT` structs:

```
const pressKey = (scanCode) => {
  const inputCount = 2
  const inputArray = Buffer.alloc(INPUT.size * inputCount)
  const keyDownKeyboardInput = KEYBDINPUT({vk: 0, extraInfo: ref.NULL_POINTER, time: 0, scan: scanCode, flags: 0x0008})
  const keyDownInput = INPUT({type: 1, union: INPUT_UNION({ki: keyDownKeyboardInput})})
  keyDownInput.ref().copy(inputArray, 0)
  const keyUpKeyboardInput = KEYBDINPUT({vk: 0, extraInfo: ref.NULL_POINTER, time: 0, scan: scanCode, flags: 0x0008 | 0x0002})
  const keyUpInput = INPUT({type: 1, union: INPUT_UNION({ki: keyUpKeyboardInput})})
  keyUpInput.ref().copy(inputArray, INPUT.size)
  user32.SendInput(inputCount, inputArray, INPUT.size)
}
```

Comment: I've read that SendInput is able to be sent multiple key-events within one function call (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput#parameters). Do you know how to accomplish this using your code/structures above? (that's something I was not able to figure out how to do)

Comment: @Venryx Check out my answer, I've updated it to include this.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, will come on handy.

Comment: Hi, I have used windows-ffi as a base for my Win32 integration. But its missing SendInput and ref-union-napi. Got some error when adding. But I should be able to fake the union by just using keyboard struct with padding. INPUT.size will always be the biggest of them (which is mouse with 32 bytes). But using this fails:

const INPUT = StructType({
  type: 'uint32',
  vk: 'uint16',
  scan: 'uint16',
  flags: 'uint32',
  time: 'uint32',
  extraInfo: 'pointer',
  padding: 'uint16',
})

Tried both key codes and scan codes as input but no luck.

Comment: Btw I did try your example just like you have it too but it fails with a cryptic error about "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'match') at new DynamicLibrary". It seems to be related to Node 18: https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi/issues/244

Answer (score 0):

The "1" tells you that 1 event was inserted, not what the event actually is.  I don't know about FFI but it seems to me that keyboardInput has some invalid type definitions. wVK and wScan must be 16-bit integers (hence the 'w' for WORD). Since they are typed the same as dwFlags (an 'int') that's cause invalid input values.