# How to send input keys to a window with node.js's ffi

Tags: node.js, ffi

How could I send input to a window using node.js ffi?

My intention is to input text and keypresses to a window whether it's in the foreground or background (if it's possible).

Answer (score 2):

You could try one of these functions.

I've collected these three key-simulation approaches for personal use, so it's kind of messy. But since your question hasn't gotten any answers yet, I figure it's better to give a messy response than none at all.

```
import robot from "robotjs";
import keycode from "keycode";
import ffi from "ffi";
import ref from "ref";
import StructType from "ref-struct";
//var ArrayType = require("ref-array");
var arch = require("os").arch();

declare var Buffer;

var user32 = new ffi.Library("user32", {
   "GetForegroundWindow": ["int32", []],
   "GetWindowTextA": ["int32", ["int32", "string", "int32"]],
   //"GetWindowTextW": ["int32", ["int32", ref.refType("string"), "int32"]],
});

export function GetForegroundWindowHandle() {
    return user32.GetForegroundWindow();
}
export function GetForegroundWindowText() {
    var buffer = new Buffer(256);
    buffer.type = ref.types.CString;
    var handle = GetForegroundWindowHandle();
    let length = user32.GetWindowTextA(handle, buffer, 256);
    return buffer.toString().substr(0, length);
}

const WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100; // key-down
const WM_KEYUP = 0x0101; // key-up
const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104; // key-down (for alt-key)
const WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105; // key-up (for alt-key)

const extraKeys = {
    leftShift: 160,
    rightShift: 161,
    leftControl: 162,
    rightControl: 163,
    leftAlt: 164,
    rightAlt: 165
};

var intPtr = ref.refType("int");

var Input = StructType({
    "type": "int",
    "???": "int", // for some reason, the wScan value is only recognized as the wScan value when we add this filler slot
    "wVK": "short",
    "wScan": "short",
    "dwFlags": "int",
    "time": "int",
    "dwExtraInfo": "int64"
    //"dwExtraInfo": "int"
});
var InputPtr = ref.refType(Input);

var user32 = ffi.Library("user32", {
   keybd_event: ["void", ["int32", "int32", "int32", "int32"]],
    SendMessageA: ["int32", ["long", "int32", "long", "int32"]],
    PostMessageA: ["int32", ["long", "int32", "long", "int32"]],
    SendInput: ["int", ["int", Input, "int"]],
    //SendInput: ["int", ["uint", ArrayType(keyboardInputPtr, 10), "int"]],
    //MapVirtualKeyEx: ["uint", ["uint", "uint", intPtr]],

    // external use
   GetKeyState: ["short", ["int"]], // not really needed, since we track each key ourselves
});

// external use
// ==========

export function GetKeyState(keyCode: number) {
    return user32.GetKeyState(keyCode);
}

// general
// ==========

enum keybd_event_flags {
    KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001, // key-down flag (kind of)
    KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002, // key-up flag
}
export enum SendMessage_Flags {
    WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100,
    WM_KEYUP = 0x0101,
    WM_CHAR = 0x0102,
}

export function KeyToggle(keyCode: number, type = "down" as "down" | "up") {
    /*if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftControl) user32.PostMessageA(GetForegroundWindowHandle(), messageType, keyCode, 0);
    else if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftShift) user32.PostMessageA(GetForegroundWindowHandle(), messageType, keyCode, 0);
    else*/

    /*if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftControl) return void robot.keyToggle("control", type);
    if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftShift) return void robot.keyToggle("shift", type);
    if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftAlt) return void robot.keyToggle("alt", type);*/

    /*if (keyCode == keycode.codes.ctrl || keyCode == extraKeys.leftShift || keyCode == extraKeys.leftAlt) {
        user32.keybd_event(keyCode, 0, type == "down" ? 0 : keybd_event_flags.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        return;
    }*/

    /*if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftControl) keyCode = keycode.codes.ctrl;
    else if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftControl) keyCode = keycode.codes.shift;
    else if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftAlt) keyCode = keycode.codes.alt;*/

    let messageType = type == "down" ? SendMessage_Flags.WM_KEYDOWN : SendMessage_Flags.WM_KEYUP;
    //if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftControl || keyCode == extraKeys.leftShift || keyCode == extraKeys.leftAlt) {
    if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftAlt) {
        messageType = type == "down" ? WM_SYSKEYDOWN : WM_SYSKEYUP;
    }

    user32.PostMessageA(GetForegroundWindowHandle(), messageType, keyCode, 0);
}
export function KeyTap(keyCode: number, includeCharEvent = false) {
    /*IgnoreNextKeyPress(keyCode);
    IgnoreNextKeyRelease(keyCode);
    robot.keyTap(keyName);*/
    KeyToggle(keyCode, "down");
    /*if (includeCharEvent) {
        user32.PostMessageA(GetForegroundWindowHandle(), SendMessage_Flags.WM_CHAR, keyCode, 0x00390001);
    }*/
    KeyToggle(keyCode, "up");
}

const INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1;

const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;
const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP       = 0x0002;
const KEYEVENTF_UNICODE     = 0x0004;
const KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE    = 0x0008;

const MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0;

export function ConvertKeyCodeToScanCode(keyCode: number) {
    let keys = "**1234567890-=**qwertyuiop[]**asdfghjkl;'`*\\zxcvbnm,./".split("");
    return keys.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toLowerCase());
}

//var EntryArray = ArrayType(keyboardInput)
export function KeyToggle2(keyCode: number, type = "down" as "down" | "up", asScanCode = false) {
    let entry = new Input();
    entry.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    entry.time = 0;
    entry.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // (virtual) key-code approach (default)
    if (!asScanCode) {
        entry.dwFlags = type == "down" ? 0 : KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        entry.wVK = keyCode;
        //info.wScan = 0x0200;
        entry.wScan = 0;
    }
    // scan-code approach
    else {
        //keyCode = 16 + (keyCode - keycode.codes.a);
        //let scanCode = user32.MapVirtualKeyEx(keyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
        let scanCode = ConvertKeyCodeToScanCode(keyCode);

        entry.dwFlags = type == "down" ? KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE : KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        entry.wVK = 0;
        entry.wScan = scanCode;
    }

    /*var array = new EntryArray(1) // by length 
    array[0] = entry;*/
    //var r = user32.SendInput(1, entry.ref(), 28);
    let result = user32.SendInput(1, entry, arch === "x64" ? 40 : 28);
    console.log(result);
}
export function KeyTap2(keyCode: number, asScanCode = false) {
    KeyToggle2(keyCode, "down", asScanCode);
    KeyToggle2(keyCode, "up", asScanCode);
}

export function KeyToggle3(keyCode: number, type = "down" as "down" | "up") {
    let messageType = type == "down" ? SendMessage_Flags.WM_KEYDOWN : SendMessage_Flags.WM_KEYUP;
    //if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftControl || keyCode == extraKeys.leftShift || keyCode == extraKeys.leftAlt) {
    if (keyCode == extraKeys.leftAlt) {
        messageType = type == "down" ? WM_SYSKEYDOWN : WM_SYSKEYUP;
    }

    if (type == "down") {
        IgnoreNextKeyPress(keyCode);
        user32.keybd_event(keyCode, 0, 0, 0);
        //user32.keybd_event(keyCode, 0, keybd_event_flags.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);

        user32.PostMessageA(GetForegroundWindowHandle(), SendMessage_Flags.WM_KEYDOWN, keyCode, 0);
    } else {
        IgnoreNextKeyRelease(keyCode);
        user32.keybd_event(keyCode, 0, keybd_event_flags.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        //user32.keybd_event(keyCode, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

        user32.PostMessageA(GetForegroundWindowHandle(), SendMessage_Flags.WM_KEYUP, keyCode, 0);
    }
}
export function KeyTap3(keyCode: number) {
    KeyToggle3(keyCode, "down");
    KeyToggle3(keyCode, "up");
}
```

Again, it's really messy, and I don't remember if all of them work. I know that at least KeyTap2 works (with asScanCode = true), because that's the one I'm currently using.

However, note that KeyTap2 does not let you target a background window -- only whatever window currently has focus. The other ones appear to let you target background windows, although I haven't tested it on background windows yet.

Note: A cleaner version of this answer (though only including the KeyTap2 approach) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50412529/2441655