# How to send keypresses through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, keypress, twitch

I am coding a twitch bot and I want it so when users type a command (something like !space [time] ) it will randomly press space for the ammount of time they gave. I know how to receive the command but i dont know how to send the key input. Thanks in advance

EDIT : When i say send keypresses i mean from the nodejs console on my end not in on twitch

EDIT 2 : I want this so viewers on my stream can spend points to troll me when i am playing games

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Twitch bots talk to the server over the network. They send it strings. The server doesn't operate a virtual keyboard. There are no keys to press.

Comment: I mean, the user types !space then on my end (cos im hosting the bot) it presses space on my keyboard

Comment: To do that you'd probably need to find a way to make your bot pretend to be a USB keyboard (and it makes the reference to being a twitch bot largely irrelevant: the problem you are asking about is node simulating keypresses locally and being triggered by a message over the network is beside the point). It's a very odd thing to want and sounds very much like an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Added more details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to simulate keyboard/mouse event in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178372/is-it-possible-to-simulate-keyboard-mouse-event-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but you can use [Nut.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nut-tree/nut-js).

Minimal Example:

```js
const { keyboard } = require('@nut-tree/nut-js');
keyboard.config.autoDelayMs = 0;

   keyboard.type("Hello World!");
```

I personally think that RobotJS uses too many dependencies. Nut.js is much easier to use and much faster to set up.

Answer (score 1):

I think [RobotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs) may help you, it allows you to automate various desktop actions programatically.

Here's an example:

```
// Require RobotJS
var robot = require('robotjs')
// Tap space key
robot.keyTap("space")
```

Comment: I cant seem to install robotjs