# Electron - Getting active text field on OS

Tags: node.js, input, electron, textfield

What I mean by it is like [Windows 10's speech dictation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/4042244) - you just launch it while having an active input field in the OS, so you can just speak and this software will insert to the active input field whatever you say.
I tried Googling but didn't find an answer.

Is it possible to get the active input field via Electron?
If so, how?

Comment: If all you need to do is insert text I would consider just emulating a keyboard instead of getting the active field as this is much simpler and I imagine it is also how that speech dictation works.

Comment: Okay, so how do I do that?

Comment: See https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully installed `robotjs` after following the [building](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs#building) section and then executing the code [in the reply to the issue](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/56#issuecomment-308739624) in order to first install `windows-build-tools`.
Then, I executed the code in the 3rd step of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897783/8309806) (except for tweaking the Electron version so it fits with `gRPC`, i.e. `--target=4.0.3` and tweaking the `--abi` value to fit my Node version - 10.15.2, so it's `--abi=64`).

### EDIT

At some point, `RobotJS` caused my application to suddenly exit for some reason.
I sought for another library and found [node-key-sender](https://github.com/garimpeiro-it/node-key-sender), which not only solved that problem but was also much simpler to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robotsjs https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs

```
var robot = require("robotjs");

// Type "Hello World".
robot.typeString("Hello World");
```

Comment: Tried installing using `yarn add robotjs`, got [this error](https://i.imgur.com/AQLUUhp.png)

Comment: looks like you need to build binaries. see https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs#building

Comment: Also I recommend you don't store your node projects within one-drive as I have seen this cause problems. If you need a cloud backup consider using a private github repo.

Comment: For serious projects, I'll use private repositories. Otherwise, I'll use OneDrive

Comment: I successfully solve this problem thanks to [this reply](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/56#issuecomment-308739624) (without `--debug`)

Comment: But now [a different problem](https://i.imgur.com/Ubj1KF7.png) occurs whenever I attempt use the function that you've used - for some reason, as this function is being called - the renderer process simply stops