# Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72

Tags: node.js, npm, robotjs

I am working on a node application. Where I have to work with [robotjs](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs). When I tried to install the package to my node app, I am getting some error.

```
Activating extension 'x' failed: The module '\\? 
\d:\x\app\node_modules\robotjs\build\Release\robotjs.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`)
```

I thought It might be because of my Node version. S0 I change my node version from v12.18.3 to v14.9.0.

But after changing that, I am getting.

```
Activating extension 'x' failed: The module 
'\\?\d:\x\app\node_modules\robotjs\build\Release\robotjs.node' 
was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. 
This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75. 
Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm 
install`)
```

After searching about my problem and `robotjs` I have found out this [robotjs-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897783/6275238).

But that is also not working for me. I tried to rebuild the robotjs package targeting NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75. Still the same issue.

After a little bit of digging, I found out that there is no node version that contained [NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/). Check the NODE_MODULE_VERSION column. Then why I am getting the error. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Try these approaches

1)You have to rebuild the package and tell npm to update it's binary too. Try:

```
npm rebuild robotjs --update-binary
```

2. if it doesn't work, You need to remove the module folder (robotjs) from the node_modules folder and reinstall it, use the following commands:

   ```
     rm -rf node_modules/robotjs

     npm install
   ```

Refer this for more [Node - was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio)

Here is the list node_module version https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

3    `npm cache clean --force`
Try following these steps if you are on [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52796884/13126651)

Comment: No result, Still same error. tried both `npm rebuild robotjs --update-binary` and `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`. After applying `npm rebuild robotjs --update-binary` error is same but after applying `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd` error change from `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72 to 83`. Can you tell me what the error trying to mean `This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 75` ??

Comment: npm rebuild using your local node , which isn't what robotjs has.This is what error means.

Answer (score 1):

this actually solve my problem

```
npm i robotjs
```

```
npm i -D electron-rebuild
```

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

```
npx electron-rebuild -f -t prod,optional,dev -w robotjs
```