# How do I cause keyboard actions with NodeJS (other than RobotJS)?

Tags: node.js, electron, robotjs

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178372/is-it-possible-to-simulate-keyboard-mouse-event-in-nodejs), I am trying to figure out how to simulate certain key commands with NodeJS. For example, I'd like to programmatically cause "ctrl+C" (copying highlighted text) to occur, no matter what window the user is in.

A common answer to this kind of question previously has been [RobotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs). RobotJS seems perfectly suited to this task--except it is no longer being maintained and as a result does not seem appropriate for production.

Are there alternatives to RobotJS, to enable causing key commands to happen?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options I'm aware of:

- [`@nut-tree/nut-js`](https://github.com/nut-tree/nut.js) uses its own implementation based off of RobotJS and seems to be actively maintained.
- If you don't mind platform-specific utilities, you could execute native scripts through Node.js child processes (AppleScript, PowerShell, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've seen references to child processes like you mentioned (AppleScript, and maybe with spawn). But I don't have a good sense of what that would involve. Are you familiar with any example code for that ?

Comment: There are a couple NPM libraries out there that can help you out with that (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell or https://www.npmjs.com/package/applescript